# Should I buy Duracell or a much cheaper battery?

Tags: batteries

So, here are two different batteries. Both are AAA and 1.5 Volt Alkaline batteries.
(The currency is Turkish lira and prices apply to Turkey. You can think of them as dollars or euros if that makes it easier :D)

Duracell: 1400 mAh, 1.5V (3₺ per battery)
Inflame: 1300 mAh, 1.5V (0.66₺ per battery)

In a capacity-price ratio (capacity per 1₺), Inflame battery wins by a lot. And I know that popular brands usually have a high profit margin - like Apple. I'm wondering if it's the same case here. Is it only the capacity in mAh that matters? Or are there other things to be considered?
I'm asking this for my wireless mouse. The Inflame battery usually lasts around 2-3 months. And Duracell claims to have 10 times more durability against cheaper batteries... Should I believe it? If I get Duracell, will I get like 20-30 months of durability in my mouse?

(Mouse: inca - it says it consumes 1.5v 30mA)

Comment: Not all batteries are created equal - your best best is to buy one and try it. Best test is to write the date on the battery when you fit it, then you can be certain of the duration.

Comment: Be the first to test and report back the results.  3₺=0.49usd We hope "Inflame" does not imply what happens to you when they cut out before expected time.

Comment: Almost all the reports I've read over the past 30 years essentially say to buy the cheapest.  In the US I think the best buy is ACDeleco (Genuine GM auto parts) sold online with free delivery by Home Depot in quantities of 60 or 100 at 25¢ each.  In store Rayovac at 37¢ is  a fair deal especially when they are discounted ≈27¢.  --- @TonyEErocketscientist  Good one.

Comment: I  agree so I buy bulk Dynex  ~$10 (100 pc AA) or Panasonic Lithium when the best matters

Comment: I've had issues with the Duracell batteries leaking multiple times. Never faced that with Energizer though (or maybe it's just my experience). I've had Energizers 5-6 yeras past expiry date and they worked fine. Again as others have mentioned here price sometimes isn't always directly related to quality.

Answer (score 4):

According to tests, Costco (North American warehouse wholesale store) Kirkland store brand AA batteries are about as good as Duracell for a fraction (about 1/3) of the price.

If both your batteries are alkaline batteries **and** have similar mAh rating, they should last a similar length of time with similar current draw.

It's quite possible to come up with "advertising" comparisons that would appear to show a 10:1 advantage for an alkaline cell by deliberately choosing an application with a high current draw and comparing the alkaline cell with a cheap "heavy duty" zinc-carbon cell.

Comment: Results of Consumer Reports test of 13 AA Alkaline. --
Duracell Quantum 89 ---
Rayovac Fusion Advanced 85 ---
CVS Max 82 ---
Duracell Coppertop Duralock 80 ---
Kirkland Signature (Costco) 80 ---
Rite Aid Home 79 ---
AmazonBasics Performance 71 ---
Walgreens W Alkaline Supercell AA 71 ---
Energizer ecoAdvanced 68 ---
Energizer MAX +PowerSeal 67 ---
CVS 62 ---
Dynex (Best Buy) High Capacity 60 ---
EcoAlkalines 59

Answer (score 1):

If Duracell says it is 1400 mAh, it likely is 1400 mAh under decent load.

If no-name "Inflame" says "1300 mAh", it needs to be verified under which conditions they claim this capacity. So before making any conclusion which battery will last longer, you need to either find guaranteed datasheets for this battery, or conduct your own capacity measurements under the load of your use. And maybe run the Duracell under the same condition and compare.

But keep in mind that the battery capacity might be not the whole story. For example, reputable batteries don't leak internal electrolyte as the other batteries might do, so they are safer to use and won't destroy your mouse or whatever.

Anyway I would doubt very much that the cheap battery has 1/10th of capacity of the Duracell, maybe only 1/2 of it, so the price/capacity ratio might be in favor of the cheaper battery.

Comment: The better battery isn't always the most expensive. I remember reading that Kirkland (Costco) batteries beat Energizer or Duracell in a test. But Kirkland isn't a no-name brand, either.

Comment: I wonder if P.R.C. still use Mercury in batteries.

Comment: @piojo, actually it might be very likely that both core cells are made on the same factory on the same production lines :-)

Comment: I've watched a YouTube video that tested this. He tested both of them in a current of 0.2 amps and the guy came to this conclusion of 1400 vs 1300 mAh battery.
By the way, I'm pretty new to this electricity measurement things and I recently heard that if you lower the amps, you'll get more mAh on your battery. Is it true? So if the battery is 1300 mAh under a 0.2 amp load, how many mAh is it on a 0.03 amp load?

Comment: They are only as good as the quality seal against corrosive leakage

Comment: @BurakOkuroğlu, yes, it is true that lower (and impulse-like) discharge leads to bigger capacity. Actually, according to your data (2-3 months of service time), your mouse consumes under 1 mA of current on average use, not 30. So you should expect the battery to last even longer. How longer? I will leave the answer to yourself and to your Google searching skills.

Comment: But on the website it says it uses 30mA and like I said on average it lasts 2-3 months.

Comment: @BurakOkuroğlu, it likely uses 30 mA when it is active. When you sleep, the mouse also sleeps and likely consumes nothing. 2 months is 1440 hours. Think of this.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  FYI I found 174 different factories that make Alkaline cells, FOB Price: US $ 0.015-0.09  50k to 5K qty.

Comment: Some only spec 2~3yr shelf life vs 8~10yrs